# jQuery increasing and decreasing div height based on scroll positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

jQuery increasing and decreasing div height based on scroll positioning.

Was wondering if any of you know of any way to do this in a good way. Let's say i have a div with and id of "scroll-element" And when i scroll down the page, let's say down like 500px it starts to increase to about 200px when scrolling down and decreasing to 0px when i scroll back up. I tried a few methods but none have worked so far.

Comment: What have you already tried? Can we see your Markup, CSS and scripts?

Comment: Here is one: http://jsfiddle.net/NUEvV/3/

Comment: So, what's the difference between what you want and how this jsFiddle works?

Comment: If you check, it doesn't work as i describe above..

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/NUEvV/5/)

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var $myDiv = $('#scroll-element');
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        $('#results').text(y);
        x = y - 300;
        $myDiv.animate({height:x},2500);
    }).scroll();
});
```

Comment: Almost, but i need it to increase and decrease according to the scroll of the browser, not just show/hide...

Comment: It's not showing and hiding. It's animating to the scroll of the browser - 300. Change the "2500" to "5000" and you'll see what I mean.